# How can identify and quantify physical plant (network capacity) in my local area?

Tags: bandwidth, internet, isp, networking

I am interested in identifying physical plant and network capacity in my local area, which happens to be Boston, but could be anywhere. For example, I understand that in Boston there is something called the Boston Fiber Ring running underneath the city and there is one building I think on Washington Street where there is a huge terminus.

I want to find out what the major networks are in the city, what bandwidth/level of service they have, which buildings they connect to, and which providers operate them (COMCAST, Verizon, RCN, DSCI, XO are all in the area, for example).

The reason I ask is to make provider choices and figure out who to approach about making big bandwidth deals. In other words, I don't want to go to COMCAST and then find out later Verizon has 10x the capacity COMCAST does to my building, or even worse, find out that that COMCAST is leasing bandwith from Verizon to service me and I could have gone to Verizon and sidestepped a middleman altogether.

The way I DON'T want to do this is to go begging to 6 different providers seeing what they "offer" and basically be negotiating in the dark. I want to know their physical plant up front to know the cards they are holding before I start talking to them. How can I find that out?

Note that "retail" providers like COMCAST/Verizon are in many cases not the actual fiber owners. The actual fiber is owned by a lot of different companies. For example, in Boston there is a fiber ring operated by Last Mile Solutions which connects to several downtown buildings. If you get direct access to this ring, you can potentially get much higher bandwidth at much lower cost than, saying, going to COMCAST. COMCAST is just re-selling you Last Mile's fiber.

One idea is that I know DigSafe has a map of all the underground lines in the city, but that is obviously a pretty crude approach to making network estimations.

Another option is that I can determine the plant electronically by doing IP mapping and ferret out every single broadband router in the city. Obviously this would give me an extremely fine-grained picture of who has what bandwidth where, but I can say is that the programming, time, and cost to do this would be significant and I would like to avoid doing this if the information can be more easily obtained elsewhere.

Comment: Protip:  [Service Level Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement).  Then leave it to the service provider to worry about.  That's what you're paying them for.  Also, not having to negotiate in the dark is precisely *why* you would go to 6 providers.

Answer (score 1):

I may have answered my own question, at least partially. Apparently the FCC operates a site called the [National Broadband Map](http://www.broadbandmap.gov) which allows you to get a rough gauge of ISPs and their advertised bandwidth to an address. The output looks like this:

[image: Broadband estimate]

Of course, it would be better to know their actual physical plant (OC3 lines etc), but this is a good start.

Note that this is "advertised" bandwidth, so it is essentially "brochure" information, not really their true capacity on the block or building.